# Error using svm predict function in openCV when loading a saved file with svm load

Tags: opencv, svm

I'm trying to load a .xml file using the SVM load function in OpenCV, and then use the predict function to classify a traffic sign. When reaching the execution of the predict function an error is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE88E54008 in LicentaFunctii.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000025658FD0C0.
```

And in the console the following message is logged:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type()== 5) in cv::ml::SVMImpl::predict, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-
vc14\opencv\modules\ml\src\svm.cpp, line 2005
```

This are the first 24 lines in the xml lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<opencv_ml_svm>
<format>3</format>
<svmType>C_SVC</svmType>
<kernel>
<type>LINEAR</type></kernel>
<C>15.</C>
<term_criteria><epsilon>1.0000000000000000e-02</epsilon>
<iterations>1000</iterations></term_criteria>
<var_count>3600</var_count>
<class_count>7</class_count>
<class_labels type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>7</rows>
<cols>1</cols>
<dt>i</dt>
<data>
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6</data></class_labels>
<sv_total>21</sv_total>
<support_vectors>
<_>
  1.06024239e-02 4.48197760e-02 -4.58896300e-03 -2.43553445e-02
  -7.37148002e-02 -1.85971316e-02 -1.32155744e-02 -1.38255786e-02
  -3.20396386e-02 8.21578354e-02 7.99100101e-02 -1.21739525e-02
```

The following code is used to load the trained data from the xml file:

```
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->load("Images/trainedImages.xml");
```

Note: I'm using OpenCV 3.4.0 version.

Can anyone advise on this issue?

**EDIT 1:**
It seems that loading the trained file like this will work:

```
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm = SVM::load("Images/trainedImages.xml");
```

Comment: Hi @sixfeet! Your solution worked for me! Could you please add it as an answer? Thanks you!

Comment: Hi @GaneshTata, I've added the edit as an answer! Glad that this helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that loading the trained file like this will work:

```
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm = SVM::load("Images/trainedImages.xml");
```